# Solve problem of socket.io disconnections in nodejs when used for chat in Android

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I'm developing an Android chat app from scratch..I didn't use fire-base, one of the cons of NodeJs that I've read is that how you handle disconnection so I liked to share how I solved it I'm using socket.join() to join the user with the other client is a room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-First step is to let your server emit a hello event.

```
   io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
   //every time a new socket (connection made it will emit the hello)
      socket.emit("hello",{type:"hello"});
   //
});
```

2-Second step is to register this event on the client in a background service

```
mSocket.on("hello", new Emitter.Listener() {
          @Override
          public void call(Object... args) {
             //here try to put all your available rooms in the object
              mSocket.emit("join", object);
          }
});
```

And now all the tasks that need to be done by the client on re connection implement it inside this hello event.This example here is just joining the client with the available phone numbers...